# saving multiple string labels and array to associated array in typescript

Tags: typescript, ionic4, associative-array

I am building an ionic 4 app which has to save multiple labels and arrays to an associative array but having trouble with initializing and pushing new items to the array and editing/updating existing array items in the associative array.

```
  array1 = {
           'Question1'=>['True','True'],
           'Question2'=>['False, False'] 
           }
```

How can I do this in typescript?

Comment: You might be comming from PHP where this is possible, but JS (and TS) does not support string keys for arrays. You can use objects or a maps (where strings can be keys). `obj: { [key: string]: string[] } = { key1: ["1a", "1b"] }` or see stackoverflow.com/questions/30019542/es6-map-in-typescript

Comment: Thanks @Klímačka. Yeah i came from a PHP background I thought it would be possible since I am new to typescript. Let me look into mapping in typescript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript/TypeScript does not support arrays with named indexes, arrays always use numbered indexes. You can, however, use a simple object to do this, e.g.:

```js
    const questions = {
        "question1": [true, true],
        "question2": [false, false]
    }
    
    console.log(questions);
    console.log(questions["question1"]) // prints [true, true]
```

Comment: Thanks @eol, I will look into numbered indexes. I was also advised to look into mapping in typescript

Comment: @appdevnoobie: Happy to help, don't forget to accept this answer (by clicking the checkmark to the left) if this solved your problem.